# Loading data from SQL database into C# table execution timing problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Am I trying to load data from a database into a table in a .cshtml page. For some reason, the data from the database loads in plain text to the top of the page instead of neatly populating the table. Can anyone tell me why it might do this? Is there some execution-timing mechanic that I'm missing?

```
<div id="log_container" display="inline-block" margin="100">

    <table id="log_table">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Filename</th><th>Mark In</th><th>Mark Out</th><th>Note</th></tr>
    @using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("TestTable");
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        dataSet.Tables.Add("TestTable");
        connection.Close();

        foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Response.Write("<tr>");
                Response.Write("<td>" + row.ItemArray[0] + "</td>");
                Response.Write("<td>" + row.ItemArray[1] + "</td>");
                Response.Write("<td>" + row.ItemArray[2] + "</td>");
                Response.Write("<td>" + row.ItemArray[3] + "</td>");
                Response.Write("<td>" + row.ItemArray[4] + "</td>");
                Response.Write("</tr>");
            }
        }
    }   
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Write immediately writes to the connection, shortcutting the process of assembling your web page for output.  It should not be used in .cshtml as the output then happens before the Razor template is returned.

To do things the more optimal way, I do recommend moving your connection and such into the controller instead of in the .cshtml directly, but in order to make your code work as you intended, you only need to change it as follows.  Remove the Reponse.Write and replace it with Razor syntax.

```
@<div id="log_container" display="inline-block" margin="100">

    <table id="log_table">
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Filename</th><th>Mark In</th><th>Mark Out</th><th>Note</th></tr>
        @using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("TestTable");
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        dataSet.Tables.Add("TestTable");
        connection.Close();

        foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                <tr>
               <td>@row.ItemArray[0]</td>
               <td>@row.ItemArray[1]</td>
               <td>@row.ItemArray[2]</td>
               <td>@row.ItemArray[3]</td>
               <td>@row.ItemArray[4]</td>
               </tr>
            }
        }
    }
    </table>
</div>
```